# No clue of the cause of a weird crash during a debug session in Pydev(Chinese Locale)

Tags: pydev

Environment:
     Chinese Locale
     Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1217]
     Eclipse Version: 2020-03(4.15.0) Build id: 20200313-1211
     PyDev version: 7.5.0.202001101138
     Two interpreters tried:
     (1)Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
     (2)Python ActivePython 3.7.4 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
 on 3.7.4 (default, Jan 21 2020, 18:17:23) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Procedure:
(1) set the breakpoint at the line "here = 1"
(2) Load a debug session
(3) In Mainwindow, press characters like "a", "b",...
    The breakpoint will be triggered.
(4) Convert to Console, input "dir(a)", "a.length". After waiting for a second, the programe will be terminated.
I tried my best to rewrite the codes as simple as possible. In a debug session under PyDev/Eclipse/Windows, it reoccures again and again.
But in a run session under python/Windows, everything is fine and normal.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore

class innocent_object(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        eventtype = event.type()
        if eventtype == QtCore.QEvent.InputMethod:
            attrlist = event.attributes()
            if len(attrlist):
                a = attrlist[len(attrlist)-1]
                # suspend here, convert to Console, input the below lines:
                # dir(a)
                # a.length
                here = 1
        return super().eventFilter(object, event)

if __name__ == "__main__":    

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    main_window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_InputMethodEnabled)
    monitor = innocent_object()
    main_window.installEventFilter(monitor)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the instructions given. Which Python version are you using? If you do print(dir(a)) at that place without the debugger in place, does the issue happen too?

Comment: thanks for warm reply. I reedited and restyled the question text for your question and kindness.  The script.py works normal and fine in Python/Windows without the debugger.  I have a instinct that accessing SIP wrappers or pydev's flaws is the cause. No futher exploration with my poor knowledge of internals and time-consuming job.